# Brackets - Live Preview not working

Tags: html, css, editor, real-time, adobe-brackets

I found this awesome program(html editor) called Brackets and it's by Adobe.
Now reason why i got the editor was because i wanted to Live Preview PHP code, but i found out later that i needed a Wamp Server.

Now, i was in the mood of making an about page but i couldn't live preview. Live Preview Base URL is empty, and when i try to live preview, i get this: > http://puu.sh/aDkET/4209ec1192.png < and the lightning bolt is half orange(i heard it needs to be red to work). I have tried the lot... Entering as Live Preview Base URL to http(semicolon)//localhost:(insertporthere)/  <-- Wamp Server, tried only localhost, left it empty, I don't know how to make this work.. I am stuck and i basically need real preview..

Please, please help me! D:  I have searched the internet looking for solutions, but no. If you can, a step-by-step tutorial would be much appreciated :)

Kind regards,
- PiguFilms

Comment: This is a forum for programming questions. Use the Adobe forum instead.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you `->` [open project folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37848884/5333612)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039447/brackets-live-preview-for-mozilla-firefox-developer-edition - duplicate

Answer (score 8):

The Live Preview "Base URL" is the localhost URL that corresponds to the *root folder* of your project. Brackets uses this to map from a local path on disk to the server URL which serves up that same file: it takes the HTML file's path relative to the project root, appends that relative path onto the Base URL, and then launches the resulting full URL in Chrome.

So, for example:

- If your page is at `http://localhost/myapp/page.php` and the page.php file is in a "myapp" subfolder of your project, your base URL is just `http://localhost/`.
- If your page is at `http://localhost/myapp/page.php` and the page.php file is in the root of your project, your base URL is `http://localhost/myapp/` (this way the path is "/page.php" relative to both bases).

If you think you have the Base URL set correctly but it's still not working, try going to the same URL manually in your browser to make sure your server is operating correctly.

More details on using Live Preview with your own local server can be found here: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#lp-custom-server.

Answer (score 5):

although @ytpete's answer is the right choice for your problem but you need to do, as i say, first. In simple words, go to file(in Brackets), click **open folder** and now make the project directory exactly same as your local host server for php files i.e. C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\phpFiles (i am using Ampps and here 'phpFiles' is a subfolder inside which relies my php file and also html file too). Now you can follow steps shown by ytpete and you are set to live preview of your php file.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem as well. What I did was simply goto File->Open Folder... it all worked after all the necessary files were loaded into Brackets.

Comment: I want to use Brackets in MX Linux 21 x386 and found a Fork that are given support in: https://github.com/quadre-code/quadre and I compile it and working, but the only way to use Live Preview is with this instructions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using windows try running brackets "As administrator", worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue once I installed Xampp. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z2WatI0GMQ&t=62s) resolved it for me. Essentially just select, File > 'Enable Experimental Live Preview' should have a check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have an internet bandwidth limiter (such as NetLimiter) running while using Brackets' Live preview.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this issue for myself, I had 'Experimental Live Preview' ticked under file. I unticked it and now it accepts my 'http://localhost/mywebsite' URL when I go to live preview.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I restarted my system and then unchecked  "enable experimental live preview" in file.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, and i don't remember where i saw it, but go to : `cd $HOME/.local/share/applications` and delete everything chrome related.

This worked for me, and i didn't dare to use live preview again.

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Put your files in the same folder where you have index.html file

Answer (score 0):

I have selected the option called "reload with extension" from Bracket's debug menu and that resolved live preview issue. More details can be found [here](https://cloudconfusing.com/2019/03/22/brackets-live-preview-is-not-working-how-to-fix-it/).

Answer (score 0):

For everyone, this problem can be resolved by following steps:-

1. On menu bar, go to  File --> Open Folder (folder which have your html file for live preview)
2. Select Folder
3. Select your html file from left side bar for live preview
4. Click on bolt icon on right (preview button)

All it melts down to the fact, that you need that folder(which have your file) selected to view your output in live preview. 
Let me know, if it helps someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because it doesn't find the 'html' file. Live preview basically needs html file to run it .In my case, I have a project made in php , my file name is **index.php**,I renamed it to **index.html** and it works like charm :)