# Adobe Brackets live preview is blank. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

At first I was being sent to chrome for live preview and the page was blank. Then I started getting an error message that read: "Open an HTML file or make sure there is an index.html file in your project in order to launch live preview."

Other files I have done live preview just fine. I cannot see what is wrong with the code. I searched posts here for a solution, but could not find anything. This was the closest, but it was referring to a php file. [Brackets - Live Preview not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108420/brackets-live-preview-not-working)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="design_sandbox.css"/>
    <title>Design Sandbox<title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a test, is this working?</p>
        <div id="formpractice">
            <form>
             <p>Username:
                <input type="text" size="14" maxlength= "20" />    
            </p>
            <p>I vote for:
                <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="Ella Fitzgerald"/>
                <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="Herbie Hancock"/>
                <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="John Coltrane"/>                                               <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="Miles Davis"/>
                <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="Thelonius Monk"/>
            </p>
            <button>"SUBMIT"</button>
            </form>
        </div>    
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user3510681,

I ran your code normally in the browser and the page appeared blank. Upon reviewing the code, I see that you have not closed the 'title' tag in your HTML. Your code:

```
<title>Design Sandbox<title>
```

This is why Brackets - Live Preview is not working .Please change the title code as below and things should work fine:

```
<title>Design Sandbox</title>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Wow, unbelievable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing `<tittle>` tag properly. Their is no `/`in closing `<title>` tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="design_sandbox.css"/>
    <title>Design Sandbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a test, is this working?</p>
        <div id="formpractice">
            <form>
             <p>Username:
                <input type="text" size="14" maxlength= "20" />    
            </p>
            <p>I vote for:
                <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="Ella Fitzgerald"/>
                <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="Herbie Hancock"/>
                <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="John Coltrane"/>                                               <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="Miles Davis"/>
                <input type="radio" name="jazz" value="Thelonius Monk"/>
            </p>
            <button>"SUBMIT"</button>
            </form>
        </div>    
    </body>

</html>
```