# brackets live preview for mozilla firefox developer edition

Tags: firefox, adobe-brackets

I don't use Chrome browser. However, its very irritating that Brackets always shows live preview in Chrome. How can I set Mozilla Firefox Developer Edition as default for Bracket's live preview?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Currently using Brackets to Live Preview on Mozilla Firefox (not on the Developer Edition). I've tried Live Preview on Waterfox but I can't seem to remember if it worked or not.

Anyways, try this:

Open Brackets then on the upper part of the window, click the "Debug" button.
On its drop down menu click the "Open Preference File".

On my version of Brackets (which is the latest) it will open up two .json files: 1)defaultPreferences.json and 2) brackets.json. Just focus on "brackets.json". (If ever that the first .json file never pops-up, it's fine).

Then proceed to add this line inside the bracket:

`"livedev.multibrowser": true,`

I suggest putting this on top of the default lines. So for example, it would look like this:

```
 {
    "livedev.multibrowser": true,
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "themes.theme": "dark-theme"
 }
```

Hope this helps. If it doesn't, I suggest bringing it over to the devs.

Comment: The tab opens alright, but no live changes are applied, not even after saving the file.
So, basically it's useless, only serves as a shortcut to open the file in browser.

Comment: I believe that in the latest version of brackets you can select File -> Enable Experimental Live Preview and it should automatically set this setting to true.

Answer (score 4):

Use File->Enable Experimental Live Preview.  See documentation here https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12260

Comment: worked for me as well. I'm using it with vivaldi browser

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Brackets.
2. On the top-bar menu click on "Debug".
3. On the drop down click on "Open Preferences File".
4. It will open two files "brackets.json" and "defaultPreferences.json".
5. Add the following line to the "brackets.json" file.

   **"livedev.multibrowser": true,**
6. Save the changes and reload Brackets.
7. If you wish to make Firefox your default launch browser for brackets you will have to set it as the default browser in the browser setting and vice versa to other browsers.
8. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Debug, Open Preferences File, Brackets says that it's a read only file.  Not sure if I'm supposed to believe that or not, but I decided to.  I used Windows explorer and NotePad++ to open the file directly, which can be found here:

`C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Brackets`

I added the text `"livedev.multibrowser": true,`, but then I had to **restart Brackets** for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make firefox as default browser
2. Open brackets goto Debug->Open Preference file
3. Then it will open two files ending with .json
4. goto brackets.json after { that is on first line write this
5. "livedev.multibrowser": true,
6. Then save it and then goto
7. file->enable experimental live preview
8. Check it

It will work...