# Brackets live preview on Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, adobe-brackets, live-preview

Can brackets live preview only using Chrome?

I read that brackets 1.1 (I'm using 1.6) allows multi browser and I set this option to true but I didn't find any place to define Firefox as my browser and when clicking the live preview, Chrome opens automatically.

what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [brackets live preview for mozilla firefox developer edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039447/brackets-live-preview-for-mozilla-firefox-developer-edition)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Brackets.
2. On the top-bar menu click on "Debug".
3. On the drop down click on "Open Preferences File".
4. It will open two files "brackets.json" and "defaultPreferences.json".
5. Add the following line to the "brackets.json" file.

**`"livedev.multibrowser": true,`**

6. Save the changes and reload Brackets.
7. If you wish to make Firefox your default launch browser for brackets you will have to set it as the default browser in the browser setting and vice versa to other browsers.
8. Happy coding :-)