# Adobe Brackets Live Preview w/ PHP not working (localhost is)

Tags: wordpress, backend, adobe-brackets, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to edit my custom Wordpress theme, but whenever I specify the path to the localhost server, Brackets returns

```
'To launch preview with a server-side file, you need to specify a Base URL for this project.'
```

On my Mac, my Wordpress theme is in this directory: Users/myname/Desktop/www.scabrackets.dev/wp-content/themes/customTheme

When I go to set my Base Host URL on Brackets, I've tried literally every combination of the address above, as well as adding "/index.php" and other page names like that and just typing in http://localhost/..., but still get that error message.

I'm running the newest version of Brackets (1.7), as well as DesktopServer (newest version) to establish the local host. What am I doing wrong?? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, its cause Bracket need **open project folder**, because Bracket need load another file/asset when do a live preview. my problem solved i just click

> `file -> open folder -> project_folder`

And choose your project root folder, then try click the live preview again, its work for me