# Brackets live preview not working suddenly

Tags: adobe-brackets, live-preview

So I am editing a website for an NPO, and I am using brackets to do so. Before today, live preview was fine, and showed the whole website. Starting today, when I open live preview, the website looks blank. However, when I use dev tools, I can see all the boxes in the site highlighted when I hover over its code. I am not sure what is happening, as I am still using the original code of the website.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem suddenly and another threat helped me: [Brackets - Live Preview not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108420/brackets-live-preview-not-working)

I tried this: Open **Brackets** > click on **File** > **Open Folder** and then choose the right folder, as in your local host server for your files. 
So if your folders for all the files and your index page are in one overall folder (as example called "main" - C:\main) choose that folder and click open.

I had the problem that it didn't work because it wasn't directed to my "main" folder but a sub-folder, so it did not have access to all the .css and .js etc files.